# How to run a process from a Java application?

Tags: java, process, runtime, exec

I am trying to run a console process, to which I can subsequently write further commands. The code I have is this

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
    service.submit(new StreamReader(process.getInputStream(), System.out, "OUTPUT"));
    service.submit(new StreamReader(process.getErrorStream(), System.err, "OUTPUT"));
    //process.getOutputStream().close();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        writer.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Stream reader simply reads the `InputStream` and writes it out using a `PrintWriter`. I only see output of the cmd.exe if I close the `OutputStream`. What am I getting wrong here and how can I make the user supply further commands (if i close the `OutputStream` no further commands' output is printed to the console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should flush() the PrintWriter in StreamReader.